# SSIS Import: From Excel to SQL Server

Tags: ssis

I created a simple package that imports from Excel into SQL Server. Is there a way to add a script to this package to look into the SQL table and make sure a value from the excel doesn't already exist before it adds the data? Basically, I have someone inputting data into Excel and i will run this job throughout the day to update a table I built. I just don't want dupes. Thanks!

Comment: I’d suggest putting the data from Excel into a separate table, then having a sp called from your package that loads into the main one with conditions to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Use `Lookup component` to filter duplicates.

Comment: Thanks TZHX, I think that's the route I am going with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your Data Flow Task through a Lookup component, setting your no matching entries handler ('General' tab) to 'Redirect rows to no match output', and then import only the 'no match output' into SQL Server.

You could also put a constraint on your SQL Server table to further secure it from dupes.